# grep single digit occurs one time in line

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I need help with one grep command
-single digit occurs one time in line
my solution doesn't work

`egrep "^(\s*[1]\s*)(\s*[^1]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^1]\s*)(\s*[1]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[2]\s*)(\s*[^2]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^2]\s*)(\s*[2]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[3]\s*)(\s*[^3]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^3]\s*)(\s*[3]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[4]\s*)(\s*[^4]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^4]\s*)(\s*[4]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[5]\s*)(\s*[^5]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^5]\s*)(\s*[5]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[6]\s*)(\s*[^6]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^6]\s*)(\s*[6]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[7]\s*)(\s*[^7]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^7]\s*)(\s*[7]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[8]\s*)(\s*[^8]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^8]\s*)(\s*[8]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[9]\s*)(\s*[^9]+\s*)+$|^(\s*[^9]\s*)(\s*[9]+\s*)+$"`
  example

for example in this text

```
012 210 5   
6343 232 5 3423  
345 689 7 986 543012 210 5
```

grep color only second line.
I want to grep color every line because in each line any digit occurs one time.In first line this is 5 in second line this is 5 in third line this is 7

Comment: Can you show some sample data of what you're trying to capture.

Comment: Maybe `grep "^[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$"`? Please add some examples into the question body.

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: *in each line any digit occurs one time* - wrong, `012 210 5` contains 2 zeros, two ones, 2 twos. And a similar situation is with the 2 other lines. Perhaps, you want `grep -vE '\b([0-9]+)\b.*\b\1\b'`

Comment: only one digit must appears one time in line.Rest of them can appear more times. for example `827 214 908 4695 633 025786` this line contains three 8 three 2 two 7 ONE 1 two 4 two 9 two 0 three 6 two 5 and two 3.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/7kaNMe/1, try that one if you just have spaces and digits in the strings. Or https://regex101.com/r/7kaNMe/2 if there can be any chars besides digits. Note that `\n` is not necessary in real life, I added `\n` because of the demo string in the online tester.

Comment: it's almost work. This grep don-t color this line `234 12 43 `

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/7kaNMe/3 but it will only work with the PCRE `grep`. Either install `pcregrep` or a GNU `grep` with `-P` option. `grep -P 'pattern-here'`

Comment: it's looks good but can't do it without perl regexp?

Comment: No, you can't do without PCRE here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And is it possible to use something as (\d)(?<!\1.*)(?!.*\1) - a digit not repeated before or after? I know, that directly this syntax is forbdden. But in some other way?

Comment: @Gangnus: It is possible in .NET and PyPi Python regex. Not with `grep`, even with the PCRE option on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew And not in Java, surely?

Comment: @Gangnus That is undocumented (thus can be fixed in future versions), and does not work in all scenarios, that is why it is called a constrained-width lookbehind.

Comment: Actually, it should be [`(\d)(?<!\1.*\d)(?!.*\1)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5cd%29%28%3f%3c!%5c1.*%5cd%29%28%3f!.*%5c1%29&i=012+210+5%0d%0a6343+232+5+3423%0d%0a345+689+7+986+543012+210+5%0d%0a123+123%0d%0a234+12+43%0d%0a455)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really unsure what the expected output should be (PLEASE UPDATE IT PROPERLY TO THE QUESTION), but here using GNU awk. First test data:

```
$ cat foo
012 210 5
6343 232 5 3423
345 689 7 986 543012 210 5
234 12 43
```

Then:

```
$ awk -F '' '{
    delete a
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i~/[0-9]/)
            a[$i]++
        for(i in a)
            if(a[i]==1 && match($0, "[^" i "]*" i "[^" i "]*")) {
                print $0
                next      # second data line has 2 matches
            }
}' foo
012 210 5
6343 232 5 3423
345 689 7 986 543012 210 5
234 12 43
```

Then again, its shorter just to:

```
$ awk '{for(i=0;i<=9;i++)if(gsub(i,i,$0)==1){print;next}}' foo
```

Comment: It should also match `234 12 43` as it has `4` that is present only once in the string.

Comment: Yeah, I think I understood it now.

Answer (score 0):

A pattern that detects if a digit is unique on a line (if I'm understanding the question correctly):

For the digit 5:
`^[^5]*(5)[^5]*$`

```
^     // start of line
[^5]* // any char not 5, 0-or-more
(5)   // 5
[^5]* // any char not 5, 0-or-more
$     // end of line
```

To test all digits, it becomes:

`^(?:[^0]*(0)[^0]*|[^1]*(1)[^1]*)$` etc for all digits. The digit is captured in the first group.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lutat0/2)

- Steps: 509 steps
- Flags: g, m

Comment: It is a solution stolen from @WiktorStribiżew comment

Comment: I didn't look at any other solutions. Careful what you claim. I'm perfectly able to come up with these patterns myself. You can look at my post history.

Comment: It does not matter. The solution WAS here and you REPEAT it.

Comment: I didn't repeat it because I didn't see it. Sometimes two people come up with the same solution independently.

Comment: But when one of them comes obviously later...?

Comment: There are several issues with the solution: 1) POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups, 2) `m` flag is not necessary, `grep` works on the per line basis, 3) the regex even if written OK, does not work as already mentioned in the comments. The only `grep` based solution can be written with a `-P` option since it involves lookaheads, but it seems OP cannot use one.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. I'm aware grep works per-line. It's for the demo. This solution might be adjusted to try each individual digit pattern individually in a script. If you want a regex solution, that is. It's probably easier to count the occurrences of each digit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not absolutely sure what you're after, but if it's matching lines that only contain one instance of a digit, try this:

```
[^0]*0[^0]*|[^1]*1[^1]*|[^2]*2[^2]*|[^3]*3[^3]*|[^4]*4[^4]*|[^5]*5[^5]*|[^6]*6[^6]*|[^7]*7[^7]*|[^8]*8[^8]*|[^9]*9[^9]*
```

or `grep`ified

```
grep -x "[^0]*0[^0]*\|[^1]*1[^1]*\|[^2]*2[^2]*\|[^3]*3[^3]*\|[^4]*4[^4]*\|[^5]*5[^5]*\|[^6]*6[^6]*\|[^7]*7[^7]*\|[^8]*8[^8]*\|[^9]*9[^9]*"
```

(`-x` makes `grep` match the full line.)

The regex uses 10 identical alternations, one for each digit. Each of the alternations

- make sure zero or more of anything **but** the digit starts the line.
- match the one allowed digit
- make sure zero or more of anything **but** the digit ends the line.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kWwj34/2).